# Drawing trigonometric graphs with OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, trigonometry

I am trying to draw a trigonometric graph with OpenGL. This is a part of my code:

```
   double x = -1;
   gl.glColor3d(0, 0, 0);
   gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINES);
    gl.glVertex2d(x, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x))*0.01);
    gl.glVertex2d(x+0.01, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x+0.01))*0.01);
   gl.glEnd();

   x += 0.01;
```

This part is repeated in my full code. When this is executed, I see nothing. Can anybody tell me why this might be happening?

Comment: Is your background black? Is the context initialized? Can you draw tringles or anything else?

Comment: My Background is white and the line has a black colour and the context is initialized @MalaKa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **I do not see any loop in your code**

   and also the scales are suspicious (without matrices hard to tell) try this instead:

   ```
   double x;
   gl.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINE_STRIP);
   for (x=-180.0;x<=180.0;x+=0.01)
    gl.glVertex2d(x/180.0, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x)));
   gl.glEnd();
   ```

   it uses `LINE_STRIP` instead of `LINES` and the graph is scaled to `<-1,+1>` which is most likely your viewing area...
2. **settings**

   Also there might be other problems like the comments suggest. On top of them check the obvious:

   ```
   gl.glDisable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   gl.glDisable(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   ```

   in case they has been set from other part of your code...
3. **wrong camera settings**

   I do not see any matrix code so I hope your camera is facing the correct direction and your graph is inside frustrum or whatever you use...
4. **GL rendering**

   In case your GL code is missing or has wrong structure then it should look like this (puted together all the bullets):

   ```
   // (double) buffering
   gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
   gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // non eed for the depth although
   // here set matrices in case they are not persistent
   gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
   gl.glLoadIdentity();
   gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION);
   gl.glLoadIdentity();
   // here set/reset config the pipeline
   gl.glDisable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   gl.glDisable(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   gl.glLineWidth(1.0);
   // here render
   double x;
   gl.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   gl.glBegin(gl.GL_LINE_STRIP);
   for (x=-180.0;x=<180.0;x+=0.01)
    gl.glVertex2d(x/180.0, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x)));
   gl.glEnd();
   // (double) buffering
   gl.glFlush();
   SwapBuffers(hdc);
   ```

   I do not code in JAVA so instead of `SwapBuffers(hdc);` use whatever you got in JAVA for the same purpose. Hope I did not make any mistake while translating to JAVA.

For more info see:

- [simple complete GL+VAO/VBO+GLSL+shaders example in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

Comment: Thank you @Spektre It Works!

Comment: @kimchiboy03 now you can rem out line by line to find out what was the problem in the first place. My bet is your matrices was not set  for the scale you was rendering or at all.